# how to disable comment line wrap in WebStorm 2017

Tags: webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2017, but i have faced annoying issue with Line comments wrap

Before:

```
"devDependencies" : {
   "gulp"            : "latest", /* Manager */
   "gulp-babel"      : "latest", /* Minify JS (ES2015) */
   "gulp-babili"     : "latest", /* gulp-babel */
   "gulp-csso"       : "latest", /* Minify CSS */
   "gulp-htmlmin"    : "latest", /* Minify HTML */
   "gulp-rigger"     : "latest", /* Insert file to file */
   "gulp-sass"       : "latest", /* Compile SASS */
   "gulp-sourcemaps" : "latest", /* Sourcemap to JS\CSS */
   "gulp-uncss"      : "latest", /* Clear CSS */
   "gulp-util"       : "latest", /* Gulp util */
   "rimraf"          : "latest"  /* File delete */
}
```

After:

```
"devDependencies" : {
   "gulp"            : "latest", 
   /* Manager */
   "gulp-babel"      : "latest",
   /* Minify JS (ES2015) */
   "gulp-babili"     : "latest",
   /* gulp-babel */
   "gulp-csso"       : "latest",
   /* Minify CSS */
   "gulp-htmlmin"    : "latest",
   /* Minify HTML */
   "gulp-rigger"     : "latest",
   /* Insert file to file */
   "gulp-sass"       : "latest",
   /* Compile SASS */
   "gulp-sourcemaps" : "latest",
   /* Sourcemap to JS\CSS */
   "gulp-uncss"      : "latest",
   /* Clear CSS */
   "gulp-util"       : "latest",
   /* Gulp util */
   "rimraf"          : "latest" 
   /* File delete */
}
```

How to disable line wrap for comments? In to all formats, json, js etc...

Need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are kept on same line to me when formatting JavaScript object literals.
For JSON, try setting **Objects** to *Do not wrap* in `Settings | Editor | Code Style | JSON | Wrapping and Braces`